# How to use TinkerPop to print out an image?

Tags: neo4j, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

For example, given this graph:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern() (1)
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal(standard())        (2)
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().has('name','marko').out('knows').values('name') (3)
```

I want to print out a PNG file for this graph from the console. The documentation doesn't say how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TinkerPop doesn't provide graph visualization options directly. The best you can do is either:

1. Use the [Gephi plugin](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gephi-plugin) to visualize your graph and then save that visualization to an image.
2. Export your graph to GraphML and then import it into a visualization tool, like [Gephi](https://gephi.org/), [Cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org), etc. and then export an image generated from there.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Python at all, the networkx and matploitlib libraries can read a GraphML file and render it. I have used this in a Python Notebook with Gremlin Python running where I extracted a subgraph to GraphML and rendered it using Python.

The code would be along the lines of:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.parse_graphml(mygraph)

label = nx.get_node_attributes(G, "code")
plt.figure(figsize=(11,11))
nx.draw(G, node_color="#ffaa00",node_size=1200,labels=label,arrows=False)
```

Apologies in advance if my Python is ugly I'm more of a Ruby and Groovy guy :-)